# How can a user have only reputation from account associations alone on all accounts?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, association

[This user](https://stackexchange.com/users/412854/ranjenanil?tab=accounts) seems to have earned all their reputation from account associations alone. According to [How does "Reputation" work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work) you have to earn at least 200 on one site to get the bonus.

[image]

Comment: He's obviously [participated on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1278192/ranjenanil) before, so my guess is that he's had a number of questions/answers deleted. Before they were deleted, he had 200+ reputation, enough to earn the account association bonuses.

Comment: They must have been on another site...but I don't know how they "unassociated" themselves from that site. Did a site get burninated?

Comment: @NullUserExceptionอ_อ see my answer.

Comment: @The Establishment: I don't see any deleted posts on his SO account.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you see from the [Google Cache](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:z8ERcTj3vQkJ:stackoverflow.com/users/786160/ranjenanil+&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us) of that [user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/786160/ranjenanil), that user made a new account recently. The one that google has is an older version.

It might have something to do with accounts merging or unmerging due to sock puppets.

Comment: So I take it once the user gets the association bonus its never rolled back..

Comment: @ConradFrix I am not sure. this does seem odd.

Comment: Correct, he *had* a user that earned the bonus (later deleted) and it is never revoked.